# I have forgotten to attach visa refusal letter as additional document for second application

Tags: visa-refusals

I have applied for eea family permit visa and received a refusal letter.
Then I have applied again providing more evidences and other documents, BUT I have forgotten to attach a refusal letter of first application. Any ideas what should I do now? 
Help me please with advice

Comment: Did you provide details in the application form? If so, I doubt that not attaching the previous refusal will matter since it will already be on file in their records

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify. Putting on hold.

Answer (score -2):

You might want to go back to/call up the representative (Embassy/Consulate), and be honest

> "Hi, I realised I have forgotten to add supporting documentation, would you please append this document on to my application?"

This shows you're doing the right thing and might reflect positively as you're being honest and responsible. Not doing so may be interpreted otherwise by the officials.